# How to set a checkbox in Rails only as a visual representation of the data (Read Only)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a boolean value on a task model I want to show the value in a checkbox without the possiblity of changing the checkbox value.

**How can I achieve this? Why doesn't my code work?**

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
 <%= f.check_box :important, {}, disabled="disabled" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the api? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an easy solution. The check_box_tag or check_box just confused me and I could not call the boolean value related on the checkbox (checked = true, unckecked = false).

**This works perfectly:**

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
 <%= f.check_box :important, :disabled => true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`check_box_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) with `disabled: true`.